# Automatic Linq to SQL optimizer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

Is there any automatic or semi-automatic tool for optimizing Linq to SQL in Visual Studio?

E.g. a tool that shows tips, measures performance, highlights inefficient queries, suggests improvements.

Answer (score 1):

This morning I saw a link to this [linq optomizer](http://palladin.github.io/LinqOptimizer/) on github.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of that does everything all by itself but what I do is:

1. Run a query in LinqPad and copy the resulting SQL query (you can do it without LinqPad too but its a handy tool)
2. Paste the query to SQL Server Management Studio and select Include Actual Execution Plan from the Query menu
3. Run query

You can then analyze the execution plan non-automatically but also if there's some index missing SSMS will display a suggestion to create it together with a script that does just that.